# Normalization of grayscale fingerprint images

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to normalize grayscale fingerprint images as proposed in [this paper](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/fingerprint.pdf) in Section 2.3. To test it I used this [gray fingerprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TRNr.jpg) and after normalization I want it to look like this [normalized fingerprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj0R8.jpg).

Here is the function I used to normalize the fingerprint

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def normalization(im_arr, M0, VAR0):
    """
    im_arr: image as array
    M0: desired mean
    VAR0: desired variance

    G: normalized image as array
    """
    row, col = im_arr.shape
    # Mean and variance calculation
    M = (1 / (row ** 2)) * np.sum(im_arr)
    VAR = (1 / (row ** 2)) * np.sum((im_arr - M) ** 2)

    G = np.zeros(im_arr.shape)
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            if im_arr[i, j] > M:
                G[i, j] = M0 + np.sqrt((VAR0 * (im_arr[i, j] - M) ** 2) / VAR)
            else:
                G[i, j] = M0 - np.sqrt((VAR0 * (im_arr[i, j] - M) ** 2) / VAR)
    return G
```

and here is the code I used to read the data

```
data = 'greyfp.JPG'

img = Image.open(data).convert('L')
img = img.resize((200, 200))
img_arr = np.array(img).astype(float)
img_arr = img_arr / np.max(img_arr)

G = normalization(img_arr, 0.5, 0.5)
```

If I now check the mean and the variance of the new image, I get the desired results. But when I try to plot the normalized fingerprint from its matrix it looks exactly the same as the input image

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
grey = ax[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
norm = ax[1].imshow(G, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

However, if I save the new image and plot it with

```
img = Image.fromarray(G, 'L')
img.save('G.JPG')
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

it looks [completely different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Vbm.jpg), but still not like my desired output.

Could anybody help me to get the same result as in the paper and maybe help me understand, why the plots from the matrix and the image-type look totally different?

Comment: Check to the shape of G; I had a similar issue, and my image looked like yours. It was that I was changing the size of the array after some image operations.   I see you resize the image, for example.  Make sure the size is the same.

Comment: @asylumax I'm not too sure if I get you. G and img_arr are of the same size, namely (200, 200), since I resize the image as I read it in.

Comment: Looked at your code; G is an array of floats when it returns; if you multiply by 255, and convert to uint8, you get an image.  I think this may be it, or part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this update of your code:

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def normalization(im_arr, M0, VAR0):
    """
    im_arr: image as array
    M0: desired mean
    VAR0: desired variance

    G: normalized image as array
    """
    row, col = im_arr.shape
    print("row,col = ", row, col)
    # Mean and variance calculation
    M = (1 / (row ** 2)) * np.sum(im_arr)
    VAR = (1 / (row ** 2)) * np.sum((im_arr - M) ** 2)

    G = np.zeros(im_arr.shape)
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):

            if im_arr[i, j] > M:
                G[i, j] = M0 + np.sqrt((VAR0 * (im_arr[i, j] - M) ** 2) / VAR)
            else:
                G[i, j] = M0 - np.sqrt((VAR0 * (im_arr[i, j] - M) ** 2) / VAR)
    return G

data = 'test.jpg'

img = Image.open(data).convert('L')
img = img.resize((200, 200))
img_arr = np.array(img).astype(float)
img_arr = img_arr / np.max(img_arr)

G = normalization(img_arr, 0.5, 0.5)
G=G*255
G=np.where(G<=255,G,255)
G=np.array(G).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("G",G)


img = Image.fromarray(G, 'L')
img.save('G.JPG')
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This definitely does something, although I'm not able to recreate the desired result. I don't fully understand why one needs to convert it to `np.uint8` after I read the input as `np.float` and rescaled it to values between 0 and 1. Also I just noticed, that if I plot the gray fingerprint image using either `plt.imshow(im_arr, cmap='gray')` or `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')` it doesn't look as bad as the input picture I posted in the initial question, but I don't know why.

Comment: You need to to multiply by 255 and convert to np.uint8, because images use 0-255 as pixel scaling.   BTW, OpenCV allows you to view these arrays directly, which can sometimes be useful.

Comment: I modified the code to handle over situations where the pixell value exceeds 255.  This makes things look a lot different.  Forgot to add!  I think this gives a reasonable result.

Comment: Thank you very much so far! I think this is a step in the right direction. However I'm still not sure how I get the same result as in the paper. Also if I want to do some more computations on the normalized image, do I keep it as `dtype = np.float`? Since my final goal will be to get an orientation map of the fingerprint image.

Comment: Well, if you are doing fine scaling, keep everything as a float, and then, convert to the image (0-255) for display.  If you fiddle with the M0 and VAR0 values, you start to see differences, so I guess that's where things get interesting.  For the purposes of the program, I think this solution gets you on track.  One note; you should embed those sample images, so that people who see this in the future can get the whole picture (no pun intended).  External links can break.

Comment: Incidentally, if you use img_arr = np.array(img).astype(float), and don't divide by np.max(img_arr), you keep the pixels in 0-255; using the M0 and V0 of 100  and 100 from the paper, (and now, you don't have to do G=G*255), the image looks pretty close to the result desired.